# How to call method of class of dependency injection?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Suppose we have one class, in which both methods are annotated as beans, and method s2 need the return of s1 as pass-in parameter (dependency injection).

```
public class1 {
  @Bean(name = "s1")
  public s1 {}

  @Bean(name = "s2")
  public s2 (@Name("s1")) {}

}
```

Then now in another class, where I'd like to call method s2, then what should I do? Obviously s2 depends on s1, but how can I get and pass-in s1 in class2?

```
public class2 {
    class1 obj = new class1();
    obj.s2(???);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not valid Java code. Bean-annotated methods live in configuration class, and their goal is to create beans that are then used in the application. Spring calls these methods to create and configure the beans of the application. You shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a result of bean named "s1" in bean named "s2" it is possible.
You can put it into body of your public method s2(). There is no need to give "s1" as parameter.

```
@Bean(name = "s2")
public s2 () {
      s1();
}
```